# How to set property of QTextCharFormat in PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to set a custom property of an image inserted into a `QTextEdit`. I have the following example code which sets then outputs the value of the property to the terminal:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class TestEditor(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.layout().setSpacing(0)
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.layout().addWidget(self.textEdit)

        document = self.textEdit.document()
        cursor = QTextCursor(document)
        cursor.insertImage("./testimage.png")
        f = cursor.charFormat()
        print(f)

        prop_id = 0x100000 + 1
        f.setProperty(prop_id, 100)
        print(f.intProperty(prop_id))
        print('------')

        block = document.firstBlock()
        while block.length() > 0:
            print(block)
            it = block.begin()
            while not it.atEnd():
                f = it.fragment()
                fmt = f.charFormat()
                print(fmt)
                print(fmt.intProperty(prop_id))
                it += 1
            block = block.next()

class TestWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(HextEditor())

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.layout().setSpacing(0)
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setWindowTitle('button tooltip')
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The program results in an output of:

```
<PyQt5.QtGui.QTextCharFormat object at 0x107109ba8>
100
------
<PyQt5.QtGui.QTextBlock object at 0x105448318>
<PyQt5.QtGui.QTextCharFormat object at 0x107109ba8>
0
```

Note that the second time the value is gotten it has a value of 0 rather than 100. It even appears to be the same instance of a `QTextCharFormat`. How would I accomplish something like this? Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: charFormat() is passed by value, so a new instance is created, so you are saving the value of 100 in another new variable so you do not see that value in the loop. Also change HextEditor() to TestEditor()

Comment: If change a char-format object in any way, you must reapply it for the changes to be made permanent.

Comment: What function/method should I call to apply the change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by saving the range of the inserted image, selecting it, and using [QTextCursor.setCharFormat()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#setCharFormat) to save the changes:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class TestEditor(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.layout().setSpacing(0)
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.layout().addWidget(self.textEdit)

        document = self.textEdit.document()
        cursor = QTextCursor(document)

        # Save the position of the beginning and end of the inserted image
        p1 = cursor.position()
        cursor.insertImage("./testimage.png")
        p2 = cursor.position()

        f = cursor.charFormat()
        print(f)

        prop_id = 0x100000 + 1
        f.setProperty(prop_id, 100)

        # Select the inserted fragment and apply format
        cursor.setPosition(p1)
        cursor.setPosition(p2, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
        cursor.setCharFormat(f)

        print(f.intProperty(prop_id))
        print('------')

        block = document.firstBlock()
        while block.length() > 0:
            print(block)
            it = block.begin()
            while not it.atEnd():
                f = it.fragment()
                fmt = f.charFormat()
                print(fmt)
                print(fmt.intProperty(prop_id))
                it += 1
            block = block.next()

class TestWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(TestEditor())

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.layout().setSpacing(0)
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setWindowTitle('button tooltip')
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```